# Update table's different columns with different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql here:

```
update table_name
set column1 = new_value1,
    column2 = new_value2
    
where id = 1;

update table_name
set column3 = new_value3,
    column4 = new_value4
    
where id = 3;

update table_name
set column5 = new_value5,
    column6 = new_value6,
    column7 = new_value7
    
where id = 6;
```

Is there anyway I can make it simpler or cleaner ?

Comment: It looks simple and clean to me.

Comment: Basic and cleaner. you can write a case based query on id if you want. but this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *could* re-write this to all run in the same `update` statement, where it sets all of the columns for each id matched in the `WHERE` clause and uses `case` expressions on each column to decide to set the same value or a new value:

```
update table_name
set column1 = case when id = 1 then 'new_value1' else column1 end,
    column2 = case when id = 1 then 'new_value2' else column2 end,
    column3 = case when id = 3 then 'new_value3' else column3 end,
    column4 = case when id = 3 then 'new_value4' else column4 end,
    column5 = case when id = 6 then 'new_value5' else column5 end,
    column6 = case when id = 6 then 'new_value6' else column6 end,
    column7 = case when id = 6 then 'new_value7' else column7 end
where id IN (1, 3, 6);
```

We could further change this to use a `JOIN` expression on a [table-valued constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html):

```
UPDATE table_name t
INNER JOIN ( VALUES 
   ROW (1, 'new_value1', 'new_value2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ROW (3, NULL, NULL, 'new_value3', 'new_value4', NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ROW (6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'new_value5', 'new_value6', 'new_value7')
) map(id, nv1, nv2, nv3, nv4, nv5, nv6, nv7) ON map.id = t.id
SET t.column1 = coalesce(map.nv1, t.column1),
    t.column2 = coalesce(map.nv2, t.column2),
    t.column3 = coalesce(map.nv3, t.column3),
    t.column4 = coalesce(map.nv4, t.column4),
    t.column5 = coalesce(map.nv5, t.column5),
    t.column6 = coalesce(map.nv6, t.column6),
    t.column7 = coalesce(map.nv7, t.column7);
```

Either approach does have the advantage of automatically ensuring everything is inside the same transaction (better atomicity, if that's even a word), and I like the second option – even though it's a little more code – for the the way it treats the new values more like data.

### ... But

I wouldn't call them any "simpler" or "cleaner". What you have already is probably good enough in that regard, unless you really want the single-statement benefits.

Answer (score -1):

Make a function or trigger using parameters.  If you have a list of columns to set and a list of where columns to check, pass arrays as parameters to the function, and build the string using a loop instead of using one statement like below.  I simply have variables for each in this example rather than parameters (as variables) in a function.

Then use dynamic SQL like so.

```
DECLARE sc1 varchar:= 'column1';
DECLARE sv1 varchar := 'new_value1';
DECLARE sc2 varchar:= 'column2';
DECLARE sv2 varchar := 'new_value2';
DECLARE wc1 varchar := 'id';
DECLARE wv1 varchar := '1';

EXECUTE 'update table_name set ' || sc1 || ' = ' || sv1 || ', ' || sc2 || ' = ' || sv2 || ' where ' || wc1 || ' = ' || wv1
```

---

or

```
create function build_query(sc1 varchar, 
                            sv1 varchar,
                            sc2 varchar,
                            sv2 varchar,
                            wc1 varchar,
                            wv1 varchar)
  returns text
as
$$
begin
    return EXECUTE 'update table_name set ' || sc1 || ' = ' || sv1 || ', ' || sc2 || ' = ' || sv2 || ' where ' || wc1 || ' = ' || wv1 ;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Calling function:

```
SELECT build_query('column1', 'new_value1', 'column2', 'new_value2', 'id', '1');
```

Comment: Nothing about dynamic sql is simpler or cleaner.